# Silverlight 4.0: Cross Domain is not working in Windows XP Sp3

Tags: silverlight-4.0, windows-xp, cross-domain

I was trying to test my application created in Windows7, everything is working perfectly. When I tried to run it in WinXP SP3, I got a cross domain error. I put cross domain and client access policy to my inetpub\wwwwroot folder but still error pops. Is their anything that I missed out? Its kinda weird but its what I am experiencing.

> Again, the code is perfectly working in Windows 7.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: if you try and access the policy xml files via your browser, do they get served?  ie go to www.mydomain.com\clientaccesspolicy.xml and do you get xml returned?  What do your server logs say?

Comment: check the logs, maybe it is related top the serialisation of one of the types instead...

Comment: you need to enable logging for the service in the service config: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5960349/97614) for details of how to turn on logging.

Comment: when you say it is working in windows 7, do you mean the service is hosted in windows 7, or the client is running in windows 7 or both?

Comment: Your IIS is running on port 13328? It looks weird, since its usually on port 80 and it seems like your trying to connect to VS development server, which doesnt use xdomain policy files from IIS.

Comment: @Sam, Yes, service and client is hosted both in win 7

Comment: @Zeela, Yes. so weird because I am debugging my application thats why I am connected to VS dev server not to IIS. WHen I connect my application to IIS, it has a generic error